# Argument for "n" when plotting with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am fairly new to R (coming from a Stata-background) and I am finding difficult to deal with some arguments when plotting with ggplot2. Please consider the following:

```
test <- data.frame(
  time=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
  experiment=c(2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2)
)

test$time2 <- factor(test$time,
  levels=c("1","2","3"),
  labels=c("R1", "R2", "R3")
)

test$experiment2 <- factor(test$experiment,
                           levels=c(1,2),
                           labels=c("Yes", "No")
                           )

ggplot(test, aes(test$time2, ..count../3))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=test$experiment2))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

The above is just a silly example I just made up to ask about how to use "n" (number of observations) properly. If you reproduce the code above you will see that it graphs a stacked barplot (percentages). However, to make it I had to manually do: ..count../3

What I would like to find out in R is how to substitute that "3" by a generic argument. Looking on the Internet could not find anything, and tentatively I tried "N" and "n" to no avail. Thanks a lot for your help, the move from Stata to R is exciting but not as easy as one would think.

Comment: It's often better to transform your data before you try to plot it. Or transform the data parameter to ggplot rather than trying to transform in the aesthetics. Also, never use `$` in the `aes()` calls. That really messes things up. Just use `aes(time2, ..count..)` Also, if you just want every bar to be 100% tall, use `geom_bar(..., position = "fill")`, that will take care of the transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this particular case I was looking to make every bar to be 100%, so thanks a lot for your help. However, in a more general way: how could I call in R the total number of observations of a variable? In Stata would be "_n", but not clue in R. Cheers.

Comment: @S.Calvo try `ncol(test)` or `length(test$experiment2)` (or if you want to count the observations that are not `NA`: `sum(!is.na(test$experiment2))`).

Comment: @Qaswed Thanks a lot!!